# Getting the filename of the current input from within "show_error_hook"

Tags: errors, luatex, external-files

In the luatex reference guide, `status.filename` is described to return "the name of the current input file". The luatex wiki [describes](http://wiki.luatex.org/index.php?title=Show_error_hook&oldid=157) how to use this along with `show_error_hook` to produce better error messages that include the correct filename. However, I have found that `status.filename` always states the name of the main input file.

For example, given the file `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}

% Better error output.
\begin{luacode}
    luatexbase.add_to_callback("show_error_hook",
      function ()
        texio.write_nl("Previous error location: " .. status.filename .. ":" .. status.linenumber)
      end,
      "Machine-readable error message", 1)
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}

\input{apple.tex}

\end{document}
```

And a second file `apple.tex`:

```
\par Misplaced item: \item \par
```

Running with `lualatex main.tex`, I receive the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
Previous error location: ./main.tex:1
```

That is, the line number is correct for the error, but the filename states `main.tex` and not `apple.tex`, as I would expect.

How do I correctly get the name of the current input file from within `show_error_hook`?

Comment: Raised on luatex list: http://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2015-November/005518.html

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a bad interaction between luatex's file logging and LaTeX's definition of input. It isn't related to the error callback, `status.filename` gives the wrong file even if called directly.

Trying with the latest test release of luatex 0.85 (and a test release of latex 2016/01/01) I get result that matches the result you show with latex, but not with plain, and not with latex if I use the form of `\input` without braces.

Taking `main1.tex`  and `sub1.tex` as below, `main` may be processed with plain or latex.

---

```
\ifx\documentclass\undefined\else
  \documentclass{minimal}\begin{document}\expandafter\def\csname bye\endcsname{\end{document}}
\fi
aaa
\directlua{texio.write_nl('\string\n./main1 line 5: ' .. status.filename .. ' line ' .. status.linenumber .. '\string\n')}

aaa

\input sub1

\input{sub1}

\bye
```

---

```
xxx
\directlua{texio.write_nl('\string\n./sub1 line 2: ' .. status.filename .. ' line ' .. status.linenumber .. '\string\n')}
```

---

With plain I get on the terminal:

```
(./main1.tex

./main1 line 5: ./main1.tex line 5
 (./sub1.tex

./sub1 line 2: ./sub1.tex line 2
) (./sub1.tex

./sub1 line 2: ./sub1.tex line 2
```

showing in each case the actual printed values from `status` matching the expected values in the fixed strings.

With lualatex I get:

```
./main1 line 5: ./main1.tex line 5
(./sub1.tex

./sub1 line 2: ./sub1.tex line 2
) (./sub1.tex

./sub1 line 2: ./main1.tex line 2
```

Showing that in the last case, using the braced input form, status is showing the line number of the input file, but the filename of the top level file.

---

So as a workaround you could use

```
\input apple.tex
```

without the braces, but I'll see if we can fix that in latex (or luatex, depending where the problem is)